# How is it that the quotitient of two rationals is a common divisor for both?

Tags: arithmetic, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, divisors-algebraic-geometry

When $2$ number's ratio can not be expressed as a rational number then we call these number incommensurable.
But I also read that incommensurable also has the meaning of being able to measure two numbers by the same standard.
For example we have $$\frac{3}{4}= 0.75 \implies 3 = 0.75 \cdot 4 \\\And\\
4=\frac{16}{3}\cdot 0.75 $$
So they are both multiple of $0.75$

But what is the principle that this is based on?

Comment: If you take any two non-zero rational numbers $p$ and $q$ then there is a third rational number $r$ such that $p =r \times q $.

Comment: @badjohn: How does this show that $p$ and $q$ are always a multiple of a common number? I.e.. $p = a*r$ and $a = b*r$

Comment: Pick any $p, q, r$ then set $a = p / r$ and $b = q / r$.

Comment: @badjohn: I made a typo in my previous comment. I meant $p = a * r$ and $q = b * r$. If I pick $p = 3$, $q = 4$ hence $r=0.75$ both are multiple of $\frac{3}{4} = 0.75$ which is the part I am confused a bit. You said set $a = \frac{p}{r} = \frac{3}{0.75} = 4$ and $b =\frac{q}{r} = \frac{4}{0.75}=5.3(3)$. I am not sure I understood your hint

Comment: My point is that with the rationals, unlike the integers, you can divide anything by anything (except zero) so anything is a multiple of $0.75$ or any other standard that you choose.

Comment: @badjohn: Is there some basic principle this is based on though? What you describe is more like an observation, similar to my post

Comment: @badjohn: Do you mean that this is a "coincidence"? I.e. there is no real correlation by observing that $\frac{3}{4} = r$ then both $3$ and $4$ are multiples of $r$ i.e. it does not mean that the ratio shows they are multiples of the same number?

Comment: What's special about $0.75$?  I am sorry but this just looks like random arithmetic to me and I see nothing deep here.

Comment: @badjohn: I am trying to understand the term "incommensurable". I see that it is defined as not being able to express it as the ratio of rationals. Also I see it defined as two quantities not being able to be measured by a common measure. For the latter definition, I picked $\frac{3}{4}$ as an example and tried to understand if the division showed something about a common measure that I hadn't realized before

Comment: Terms in mathematics do not have absolute fixed official definitions.  There is no governing body dictating usage (unlike IUPAC for chemistry).  To be sure what a term means in a particular context, you need to check the author's definition.  Also, it is common for a term to have quite different meanings in different contexts.  To find a definition of your second meaning, find a use of it and check how the author defines it.  Notice that I said "a definition" and not "the definition" as another author might use it differently.

Comment: @badjohn: This helps thank you. I wasn't aware about this in regards to the terms. An example I found the definition is https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incommensurable "The side and diagonal of a square are incommensurable with each other; the diameter and circumference of a circle are incommensurable." so I was trying to understand the meaning by using $3$ as the side and $4$ as the diagonal

Comment: For the square, that is true.  For a $3, 4, 5% triangle it is not. For some triangles with two rational sides, the third might be incommensurable but it is not necessarily so.  Don't confuse "not always" with "never".